# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and auto_increment index

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

I've been scooping around in the MySQL documentation but haven't found a clear answer on the following problem.

Let's say that I have a table "users". With the following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So I have a primary key "userId" which is an auto_increment value. And a unique field "username". (So each username can only appear once, but the username should be editable).

Now I would like to know how I should use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement in this case. (Don't mind the unsecure way, but this is easier to read in this example.)

```
INSERT INTO users (`userId`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`)
VALUES('$userId', '$username', '$password', '$salt', '$email')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   username = VALUES(username), 
   password = VALUES(password), 
   email = VALUES(email);
```

What I was wondering was how I would have to insert a new user. Should I just pass a "0" or null for the UserId variable and it will create a new record with the appropriate auto incremented id? There is little information about how to use this with an auto_increment.

Because this current statement gives an error "**Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**".

Also what happens if I alter the username of a user, or if I enter a user with a different id but the same username?

***Edit***
*What I want to know is how to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY statement with a primary key that is an auto_increment. The problem is that I can't just pass on the the key in the insert statement, but I also need the key to update if it already exists. So is it possible to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY with an auto_increment primary?*

Comment: Don't even specify the `userId` in your query, leave it empty (remove both column and value from your statement). Also, inspect the actual query that mysql wants to execute and post it if you can.

Comment: Well the actual query is a bit larger than this. I simplified it for this question. But if I remove the userId colummn, how would I be able to actually update a user if it already exists?

Comment: Because username constraint will fail. It'll be the duplicate key. auto_increment won't produce duplicates.

Comment: But a username is not permanent. It would create unwanted new users when a user changes it's username.

Comment: Well, you're the person doing the task, not us.. you're the logic creator here. I don't know what your task or goal is, so if you want further comments or answers - expand the question.

Comment: What I want to know is how to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY statement with a primary key that is an auto_increment. The problem is that I can't just pass on the the key in the insert statement, but I need the key to update if it already exists. So is it possible to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY with an auto_increment primary?

Comment: Duplicate key can only be UNIQUE key (PK is unique too). That means the record is KNOWN at the point of failure. That means you don't need to know the PK whatsoever. Why are you complicating a simple matter? What you wrote is fine, your error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when you do the insert you do not include the auto_incremented index.

For Example:

```
INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`)
VALUES('$username', '$password', '$salt', '$email')
```

This is the reason why your column count doesn't match the table because it is not expecting your auto_index to be in the insert statement and therefore looking for another column

Answer (score 0):

inserting old (used) autoincrement id may be security hole in relation tables. For this reason i dont recomended this even if this is possible.